# Using Socket.io inside 3rd party widget on multiple domains

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm exploring the pros and cons of using socket.io for an upcoming project.

It is a 3rd party widget that my end users will be able to embed on their own websites.

I am having some issues while trying to implement a few tests:

1. I can't get socket.io to load synchronously, when loading the widget dependencies.
2. When I embed socket.io.js directly with the "embed code" for my widget, socket.io attempts to poll the root sites URL, not the URL of where socket.io is hosted.

So, I guess I'm here to see if anyone can provide some clarity on where I am messing up, or if this is not a viable use of socket.io (as opposed to just making json posts for recording data from within the widget).

Comment: About 2) Have you tried to connect to socket.io from the client like this: `var socket = io('http://otherdomain.com/');` in socket.io 1.0 (or `var socket = io.connect('http://otherdomain.com/');` prior to 1.0)

Comment: Zub- That did help me for one of my issues, thanks! I am now able to get connected with socket. Any idea on how I can use JS to load socket.io dependency (my first question)?

Comment: The only way to programmatically load JS file synchronously is to load its content with AJAX and then eval it, which is a big hack :) [ECMAScript 6 modules](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules_examples) should fix that, but now you only able to load it async.

Comment: Hmm.. Socket.io client side is less than ~900 lines.. Can you explore the negatives of using this hack? Seems like it could work for me.

Comment: Actually you can try it. It's only bad when debugging such scripts due to imposibility to see on which line error occurs. If you don't mind this restriction you can do that. All you need is to pass `false` as the third argument of `open` method of `XMLHttpRequest` object to send sync request. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) may help

Comment: Important note: you should be aware that while sending a *synchronous* request, browser's GUi is frozen, so user can't click on links, etc.